# LazyLogging is debug enabled?

Tags: scala, logging

I came from Java world and in Java we used to test if debug is enabled before logging with level debug. Something like this:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled)
    logger.debug("Debug")
```

This is in order to avoid evaluation of arguments passed into `logger.debug`. Do we have to do the same with scala `LazyLogging` trait?

```
class Test extends LazyLogging{
   val veryBigSeq: Seq[String] = //...
   logger.debug(veryBigSeq.toString())  //<<----- Here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, the code

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled)
    logger.debug("Debug")
```

is pretty repetitive, and can easily be generated automatically just from the part of the AST that is passed as an argument to `logger.debug(...)`. It would be surprising if this wasn't implemented as a macro. Indeed, if you take a look at the actual code in [Logger.scala](https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/scalalogging/Logger.scala), then you will see that all those `.debug` and `.error` methods are actually macros. Therefore, all the boilerplate will be added automatically, no `if`-s around each `.debug` are required.